# css html form missing border and alignment of box text

Tags: html, css, forms, border, text-alignment

Have some difficulties in placing a form in a box. It does not turn out well. i am curious if anyone has a suggestion. This is a form that is going to be placed at the side of the a dynamic text. I am also curious how to move the box text one step to the right since the text is one letter longer than the one above. Nothing fancy but the alignment and form box is crucial. [Illustration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FAQev.jpg)

A picture of the form i want :

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="action_page.html">
      <form>
    <h1>Text<h1></br></br>
    Name: <input type="text" name="Name" placeholder="Name hier.."></br>
    Epost:  <input type="text" name="Epost" placeholder="Epost hier.."></br>
     <input type="submit" value="Senden">
      </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi Erika, welcome to SO. Please take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) of the [help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to see [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and what types of question are [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for the site.  It is expected that you at least attempt to have a go at solving the problem yourself and if you get stuck with a particular part of your code , then ask a question about it.  In it's current form, your question is too broad and therefore off topic for SO

Comment: So instead of complaining that the question is too broad, why don't you modify the title so it is narrow enough for the form?

Comment: That's for you to do - you want help so why should I edit your question? Also, you have included no css which is why this is too broad - editing the title won't make this any less broad.  Also no need to be rude, that's not the way to get help on here.  Finally, I'm not complaining - I'm pointing out the rules of SO, which you clearly can't be bothered to read

Comment: You is the one that is complaining about the title being too broad, the syntax check at SO did not complain nor did the W3 html syntax check. When I meet your insensitive complaints with arguments it is my fault. I did not look for you to pick on. Besides when looking at the previous postings one can find much broader and unrelevant titles. No one told those guys they had modify their titles or code.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Overflow! I'm afraid you are taking Pete's guidance the wrong way. The help links are there to help you ask a better question, which helps you receive better answers, not to "pick on" you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using it and see if it helps:-

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

input[type=text], select, textarea {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  resize: vertical;
}

label {
  padding: 12px 12px 12px 0;
  display: inline-block;
}

input[type=submit] {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: right;
}

input[type=submit]:hover {
  background-color: #45a049;
}

.container {
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  padding: 20px;
}

.col-25 {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  margin-top: 6px;
}

.col-75 {
  float: left;
  width: 75%;
  margin-top: 6px;
}

/* Clear floats after the columns */
.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

/* Responsive layout - when the screen is less than 600px wide, make the two columns stack on top of each other instead of next to each other */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .col-25, .col-75, input[type=submit] {
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 0;
  }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <form action="/action_page.php">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-25">
      <label for="fname">Name:</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-75">
      <input type="text" id="fname" name="Name" placeholder="Name hier..">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-25">
      <label for="fname">Epost:</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-75">
      <input type="text" id="fname" name="epost" placeholder="Epost hier..">
    </div>
  </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="row">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </div>
  </form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I Have added CSS also u can see the respective element and add to you code to get the desired effect.Please upvote if it helps.

Comment: I am new to this but I gave toy the green "tick". Thanks for your swift response. I highly appreiate your contribution. Say hello from me.

Comment: Thanks alot @Erika

Answer (score 0):

Please try something like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <form action="#">

    <h1>Text</h1>
    <div class="input-wrapper">
      <label for="name">Name</label>
      <input type="text" name="Name" placeholder="Name" id="name">
    </div>

    <div class="input-wrapper">
      <label for="email">Email</label>
      <input type="text" name="Epost" placeholder="Email" id="email">
    </div>

    <button type="submit">Send</button>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

After adding some CSS for styling, this can be the result:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QobvQL?editors=1100